# After booting elementry from USB Stick it crashes

Tags: release-freya, boot, usb-drive

after booting stops elementry on the desktop.

Only the desktop wallpaper and the Mouse cursor can be seen.
The computer responds to nothing.
I tried Freya 32Bit and 64Bit.
Why is that?
On another PC running without any problems?
The PC is a / CPU 4000+ / 3Gb DDR2 / FX5200.
Please help me because I find Elementry simply brilliant.

Sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly sure what could be the issue, but try the following:

1. The crash doesn't allow you to do anything ? Can you access the terminal by clicking Ctrl+Alt+F1 ?
2. I think it might be related to your Graphic Card, but it's too early to say. Trying 1) will give a hint, and you might try to see if your WiFi or LAN is connected. If so, you might be able to troubleshoot better downloading Graphic Card drivers, eg. latest Nvidia ones.

Comment: Hi,
i wil test that Wensday. Thanks 4 Answer.